# Android activity takes 3 seconds to display

Tags: android-intent, android

When I click on the start button it takes around 3 seconds to display the next UI.

I tested without the Threads of the second activity but result is same. It takes 3seconds and 552 ms to display. The second activity contains 7 `TextChangeListner`s for 7 `EditText` fields.

This is an Android tablet application mainly for a Galaxy Tab 10.1. I am using Android 3.2 to build this app.

Comment: use asynktask to implement the listeners in ur edittext. put the initialization of edittexts in onPreExecute() and set listeners in onPostExecute() keep doInbackgroundEmpty(). So it will display the UI atleast.

Comment: can you give an example.

Comment: this is all you want with threads, handlers and asynctask nice tutorial. try it: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: I have remove all the threads but still the problem is same.

Comment: Not working. :( now it takes 3s 576ms.

Comment: what else you doing except of setting listener on edittext?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12680/discussion-between-chrishi-and-mak-just4anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason for the low performance. Its because the emulator. When I check with real device it works fine.